# Client backup solution for small (100-150 user) homogenous win/nix/mac office?

Tags: backup

We are currently using Symantec Backup Exec with Desktop and Laptop Option for our Windows clients, time machine for mac and offer simple rsync to linux users, in addition to home folders that are always backed up and available.

We are not overly happy with the horrid complexity and multitude of minor bugs in SBE, but "when you don't touch it, it mostly works".

Ideally we'd like to offer a real and full backup solution to all clients, but mostly to Linux users, as they don't have a good alternative.

I have barely tested [Druva](http://www.druva.com/) on windows, and it is promising in its simplicity and "it just works" looks, but does anyone have experience with it?

[This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/64423/open-source-backup-solution-for-windows-mac-and-linux) lists some that I will look at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not backuppc ?
http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: After read up on the docs backuppc looks as such a good alternative that I will mark this as the answer. There is the "open source" skepticism from management, but I will test it and if it holds up, recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend one of the rebrands of the one I use: http://www.clunkclick.net/online_pro.html. I use http://mybackups.co.za/ for myself but both come from the same company Attix5 (http://www.attix5.com/) and it works on Windows/Mac and Linux.

I feel obliged to say that I work for the company Attix5 (Development not Marketing), but I can sleep peaceful at night after telling you that it is a sound product that is easy to use and has a broad customer base across Europe and Africa.

Comment: Sounds good, I will see if I can run a small test setup of it.